# Is there a way to access and connect to Wi-Fi access points on client side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browser, iot

I am developing an IOT application where I need to scan available WIFI access points on client side, connect to each of them one by one and do a RPC call to set come configuration.I tried using node-wifi package but it didn't work on client side.I have researched on this issue and found browser don't have an API to access such information.Is there any possible way to achieve this in react app.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this in react-native if not in react?

Comment: Please provide more detail info. What OS platform were you using?What is your IOT application?

Comment: OS is ubuntu, IOT application is about setting configs of nodemcu modules. every module acts as a wifi access point in configuration mode, i just need to connect to each of them and do a rpc call to set some configurations specified by user. RPC call should be made only after connecting. The issue is I am unable to scan or connect to these wifi access point from browser.